# mysql case insensitive field names

Tags: mysql, case-insensitive

I understand that "TABLE" names are case sensitive (depending on OS, linux or windows), however I found that the field names are case sensitive too. I read a few places saying they are NOT. I found lots of info on TABLE NAMES, but not much on FIELDNAMES.

However this example gives an error complaining.

fieldname = "Name"
if i do the following - it errors out

edit: forgot: looking for a run time fix as this is not my db.

```
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE name = 'something'
```

This gets an error unless I change the `'name'` to `'Name'`.
2 Questions
If this is an error on my part, what am I dong wrong?
If not, is there a flag to set to control this. Seems like when the devs monkey with the database, sometimes they change fields for w/e reason, and end up with camelCase .

It just seems that I have to write redundant code to accommodate the case sensitive searches. (That is why I think I might be in error)

Comment: I actually redid this a little differently, apparently the error is not from the query itself from the from result string [code]while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql) ){
        echo $result['Title'];
        }[/code] the result is case - sensitive - how do I prevent that?

Comment: ["Column, index, stored routine, and event names are not case sensitive on any platform, nor are column aliases"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html), so please post the exact `CREATE TABLE` and error output.

Answer (score 0):

This is based on your comment that PHP is case sensitive with echo $result['Title'];

Here's a PHP function that allows you to use case insensitive indexes in PHP for associative arrays.

```
$test = array("Name"=>"Russell");
echo value($test,"name");

function value(&$row,$field) {
    // Get the value of a field.
    foreach($row as $key=>$value) {
        if (strcasecmp($key,$field)==0) {
            return $value;
        }   
    }
    throw new Exception("Field $field wasn`t found.");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Russell, I think that does the tricfk, I was hoping that I misread the docs and thought there was a switch I could use in the SELECT query. You can hard code it in the .ini file, but not really the ave. I want to go. I'll tinker with this and see who it works.

Answer (score -1):

I think lower_case_table_names system variable for mysql at your machine is set to 0 which is for case sensitive

If set to 0, table names are stored as specified and comparisons are case sensitive. If set to 1, table names are stored in lowercase on disk and comparisons are not case sensitive. If set to 2, table names are stored as given but compared in lowercase. This option also applies to database names and table aliases.

For your reference please find the below link.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

I hope this will solve your problem